# How can I edit my MS Teams meeting recordings?

Tags: sharepoint-online, video, edit

When my MS Teams meeting recordings were automatically saved in Stream, I could easily edit the video, or at least trim the messy beginnings and endings of my meetings.

Now that my MS Teams meeting recordings are automatically saved in SharePoint, I don't know what I can do edit them anymore. Is there some way to copy them to Stream and edit them there? (Aside from downloading from SharePoint and then uploading to Stream.)  Or is there another way that doesn't inolve Stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, you could opt out of OneDrive for Business and SharePoint to continue using Stream with following Teams powershell:

```
Set-CsTeamsMeetingPolicy -Identity Global -RecordingStorageMode "Stream"
```

More information for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/MicrosoftTeams/tmr-meeting-recording-change#opt-out-of-onedrive-for-business-and-sharepoint-to-continue-using-stream

Comment: Thank you, Julie -- this is very helpful.  However, does this mean that one has to be using MS Teams on Windows to do this?

Comment: Update -- I just saw that Powershell is available for Macs, too, so I can attempt your suggestion.  Thanks again!

Comment: I can't seem to make this work:  Is this something only an admin for the institution's MSFT environment can do?  Or can a simple user do this too?