# How to create a SharePoint page that displays a collection of MS Teams meeting recordings?

Tags: sharepoint-online, page-layout

This is related to me previous question, [How can I edit my MS Teams meeting recordings?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/297402/how-can-i-edit-my-ms-teams-meeting-recordings): Previously, I would create a tab in MS Teams that was automatically populated by the content from a chosen Stream channel.

Visually, this would result in a page that was tiled by video icons, in much the same way that the Activity section of a Team's automatically created SharePoint page is. (Although the Activity section displays tiles for more than just recordings, as you can see.)
[image]

Currently, the MS Teams meeting recordings are automatically saved in SharePoint -- is there a way to create a page in SharePoint that only displays the tiles from these meetings?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to store the saved content in a library,and then add this library to your page.

[image]

Reference:

[Create and use modern pages on a SharePoint site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-and-use-modern-pages-on-a-sharepoint-site-b3d46deb-27a6-4b1e-87b8-df851e503dec)

[Using web parts on SharePoint pages](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-web-parts-on-sharepoint-pages-336e8e92-3e2d-4298-ae01-d404bbe751e0)

Comment: Thanks, Elsie, but is there a way to have the files displayed as in my screenshot?  Changing the view from text to tiles only produces an images of a screen, without the meta-data that appears in the bottom white part of the tiles in my screenshot.