# How to display a video recording as a tile that include metadata, like in the 'Activity' section of a group's page?

Tags: metadata, video, tiles

This is a narrower follow-up question to my previous question, [How to create a SharePoint page that displays a collection of MS Teams meeting recordings?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/297432/how-to-create-a-sharepoint-page-that-displays-a-collection-of-ms-teams-meeting-r/297457).

If I create a document library to store a video recording and switch to tile view, I get this:

[image]

which is only an image of the screen, whereas if I check the 'Activity' section of Home page, I get this:

[image]

which includes metadata below the image of the screen.

Is there a way to have the document library tile display the larger image that contains metadata?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding a 'Quick Links' web part to the Home page on SharePoint, and editing the web part to select the 'Grid' layout, the metadata displayed on the video tiles and arrangement of tiles replicates the appearance of a Stream tab in MS Teams, which is what I was looking for.